# Flink multiple keyBy() on Stream

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a `SingleOutputStreamOperator` on which I do some processing and for which I need to do multiple `keyBy()`.

Here is an example code :

```
public SingleOutputStreamOperator<Map<String, Object>> process(DataStreamSource<Map<String, Object>> stream) {

    BroadcastStream<Map<String,Object>> broadcastedStream = ...;

    return stream
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(...)

        .keyBy(new MyKeySelector("fieldAAA"))                                           
        .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30), Time.seconds(10)))    
        .aggregate(new MyAggregationFunction1()) 

        .keyBy(new MapKeySelector("fieldAAA"))                                           
        .connect(broadcastedStream)
        .process(new MyEvaluator())             // <-- 'fieldBBB' is built here

        .keyBy(new MyKeySelector("fieldBBB"))                                            
        .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(30), Time.seconds(10)))     
        .aggregate(new MyAggregationFunction2()); 
}
```

But I get the following error :

```
2019-10-10 10:40:07.664 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task  - Co-Process-Broadcast-Keyed (6/12) (50ed3ab36b8f4078d865b7026cab08e5) switched from RUNNING to FAILED.
java.lang.RuntimeException: null
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.collect(RecordWriterOutput.java:45)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:718)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:696)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51)
    at my.package.processElement(MyEvaluator.java:54)
    at my.package.processElement(MyEvaluator.java:22)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.processElement1(CoBroadcastWithKeyedOperator.java:113)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:238)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.TwoInputStreamTask.run(TwoInputStreamTask.java:117)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:300)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupRangeAssignment.assignToKeyGroup(KeyGroupRangeAssignment.java:59)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupRangeAssignment.assignKeyToParallelOperator(KeyGroupRangeAssignment.java:48)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.partitioner.KeyGroupStreamPartitioner.selectChannel(KeyGroupStreamPartitioner.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.partitioner.KeyGroupStreamPartitioner.selectChannel(KeyGroupStreamPartitioner.java:32)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.api.writer.RecordWriter.emit(RecordWriter.java:128)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.RecordWriterOutput.pushToRecordWriter(RecordWriterOutput.java:107)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

From the stacktrace, it look like the error is inside the `processElement` function of `MyEvaluator` (KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction)  :

```
@Override
public void processElement(Map<String, Object> value, ReadOnlyContext ctx, Collector<Map<String, Object>> out) throws Exception {
    List<Map<String, Object>> newFieldsList = ... ; // Retrieve a list of new fields based on 'value' and elements received using the broadcastedStream

    for(Map<String, Object> newFields : newFieldsList){
        value.putAll(newFields);     // Add all newFields to current value
        out.collect(value);          // <-- NPE occur here
    }
}
```

But in my processing, if I remove the part with the `keyBy("fieldBBB")` the code runs. And more interesting, if I simply replace `keyBy("fieldBBB")` by `keyBy("fieldAAA")`, the code runs.

How do you explain this behavior and how can I do what I want to do ?

Comment: Is fieldBBB a public variable on the class?

Comment: No, `fieldBBB` is generated in the `processElement`. It's one of the `newFields` that are added to `value`

Comment: It looks as if `MyKeySelector("fieldBBB")` returns `null`. This might either be cause by a bug in your code or you do not add the field `"fieldBBB"` to the `value` map.